# server responded with 404. ajax call is not reaching the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am writing an application that which takes a string from text box and calls a server method on button click. However i get the error saying: 
http://localhost:33655/Search/Search1 404 (Not Found)
on inspection: i see the error. Failed to load resource. Server responded with 404.

Here is my js and controller code.

```
function look_up_term() {
    var search = {};
    var Query = document.getElementById("SearchString").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Search/Search1',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: Query,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

**controller code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using WebApplication1.Models;

    namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
    {

        public class SearchController : Controller
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult Search1(String sLookupIds)
            {    
                return Json(new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = "Result"
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Replace [HttpGet] with [HttpPost] first

Comment: Thank you Ali I made the change. I was able to get rid of that error. However now i get this error.  POST http://localhost:33655/Search/Search1 500 (Internal Server Error)    
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Search1(String sLookupIds)
        {

           // LoginViewModel model = null;
           //String renderedHTML = FakeController.RenderViewToString("Account", "Login", model);
           //return Json(renderedHTML);

            return Json(new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = "Result"
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: Note that `return Json()` is a shortcut for writing `return new JsonResult()`, so nesting one in the other is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace [HttpGet] with [HttpPost] first.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Search1([FromBody]String sLookupIds)
{
    ...
}
```

What does Query variable holds in your ajax call? Try sending data like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Search/Search1',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(Query),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. It did not change anything :(

Comment: Did you tried {"sLookupIds": Query}? Can you tell what does Query holds?

Comment: data: {"sLookupIds": Query}, // i see this in runtime -> Query="kjh". The dat a is being received properly.. "kjh" is my test string.

Comment: @codingyo I have updated my answer, please give it a go now. It should work now